# Simple Matrix class, error: calling private constructor

Tags: c++, matrix

I am learning C++ and trying to construct a simple Matrix class. The basic case I have defines the Matrix class as:

```
class Matrix {
    int r; // number of rows
    int c; // number of columns
    double* d; // array of doubles to hold matrix values
    Matrix(int nrows, int ncols, double ini = 0.0);
    ~Matrix();
}
```

And the constructor/destructor are:

```
Matrix::Matrix(int nrows, int ncols, double ini) {
    r = nrows;
    c = ncols;
    d = new double[nrows*ncols];
    for (int i = 0; i < nrows*ncols; i++) d[i] = ini;
}
Matrix::~Matrix() {
    delete[] d;
}
```

**Problem:** when I instantiate the class Matrix by calling `Matrix my_matrix(2,3)`, I get the following errors: `error: calling a private constructor of class 'Matrix'`,`error: variable of type 'Matrix' has private destructor`.

**Question:** Why is this happening? How can I understand what is failing? Could someone point me towards the solution/reading materials to help me understand this problem. Thanks for helping!

Comment: You will be in for more pain by using pointers instead of `std::vector<double> d;`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm following a book on C++ and finance (by Schlogl), it might be outdated. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Don't know if it's outdated or just using outdated teaching style.  What you have now is not adequate for a Matrix class if your intent is to start copying, returning, or passing `Matrix` objects around.  Read up on the rule of 3/5/0.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Good to know that! I will try to find some other source for that. If you have any recommendations please let me know! Thanks for your help! It also might be just an example of how to create a Class in c++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the access to properties/methods of a class is private. Add a `public:` statement in your class:

```
class Matrix {
    int r; // number of rows
    int c; // number of columns
    double* d; // array of doubles to hold matrix values
public:    
    Matrix(int nrows, int ncols, double ini = 0.0);
    ~Matrix();
}
```